# account login slow in Centos

Tags: login

My centos server recently found that the login is too slow.

I use SSH to connect the server but it seems no the problem about SSH.

Because

```
Last login: Mon Jan 26 12:11:04 2015 from XXXXX
```

appear promptly.

But

```
[username@localhost ~]#
```

this may come out after 5~10 seconds.

Does anyone know what may cause this problem?

The server has enable NIS, but it would not be the network problem since the login database stores in the mentioned slow login server

Comment: Is spawning a new shell after you login also slow?

Comment: Might be something slow in your `.bashrc`? Or your home directory being mounted on demand from a remote server. (Is opening a second session also slow?)

Comment: What is the content of the files `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, or any other file that your login shell might read? Is your home directory mounted over the network (what's the output of `df -T ~`)?

Comment: To jordanm: Yes, slow even open a new terminal window

Comment: To Ulrich Schwarz and Gilles: The home is mounted by the local storage. It was not slow before, it just happened some day and all the user login slow down

Comment: Is it a virtual environment ? VMWare tools adds script tha may hang for a while (looking for cdrom for example).
If you want to check, see here: [10-second-delay-between-login-and-shell-prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413975/10-second-delay-between-login-and-shell-prompt/40614370#40614370)